# What is the username and password for Cloud SQL instance?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

lets say that may app has:

GAE app id: `foo123`
GAE app name: `foo`
GAE cloud SQL instance id:  `foo123:myInstance`

I have set the root password to "foobar" in the access control of the Cloud SQL instance.

```
    try{

   $pdo = new pdo("mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/foo:foo123:myInstance;charset=utf8", "root", "");

}catch(PDOException $ex){
    die(json_encode(
        array('outcome' => false, 'message' => 'Unable to connect')
        )
    );
}
```

But it can not connect. I'm testing from localhost:8080. 
The Cloud SQL instance location is USA and my location is Europe.

How can I see what is causing this?

Thanks.
I have also tried root@"" with no success.

I'm doing exactly as the docs in here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/cloud-sql/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are connecting from your local computer you should connect using your instance IP address. Check the [Configuring Access for IP Connections](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/access-control#appaccess) section of the Cloud SQL documentation. You should also assign a password to your `root` user (explained also on the same page).

I am not familiar with `pdo`, but a quick Google Search shows that then you could do something like this:

```
new PDO('mysql:host=<cloudsql-instance-ip>', 'root', '<your root password>');
```

Comment: Ok. The problem was that I hadnt assigned any ip adreess. I thought that it would work from localhost too. Thanks Juan!